# Typescript: Preserving json key order with own type/class/interface

Tags: json, typescript, object

I'm getting a JSON object from a database.

I'm mapping it to a json object.
The problem is, my database has column name length limitations which requires me to manually assign some values.

Part of the model:

```
...
InvoiceLineBaseQuantityUnitCode: string;
InvoiceLineSubTotalTaxCategoryID: string;
InvoiceSubTotalTaxCategoryPercent: string;
InvoiceTaxTotal: string;
"InvoiceTotal/InvoicePayableAmount": string;
InvoiceLineID: string;
WST: string;
VERFAHREN: string;
BxLxH: string;
GEW: string;
HINWEISE: string;
ilbquc: string;
ilsttci: string;
isttcp: string;
it: string;
```

Where i reassign the values correctly and delete the temp values:

```
item.InvoiceLineBaseQuantityUnitCode = item.ilbquc;
item.InvoiceLineSubTotalTaxCategoryID = item.ilsttci;
item.InvoiceSubTotalTaxCategoryPercent = item.isttcp;
item['InvoiceTotal/InvoicePayableAmount'] = item.it;
delete item.ilbquc;
delete item.ilsttci;
delete item.isttcp;
delete item.it;
```

Unfortunately, this adds the keys at the end of the object and does not "overwrite" the existing keys.

The endpoint where we are sending the object to, requires to have the specific order of keys, like the model has.

Is there any opportunity to "remap" this object to the class so we can have the correct order of the keys? Or is there a way to order by class property?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'd say that if something external truly cares about JSON property order, then you should just output JSON directly and not go through an intervening JS object.  Otherwise you're relying on JS property order in a way that not all runtimes can guarantee.  I suppose if you're sure that you've got a ES2015+JS runtime and none of your keys are numeric-like, then it's fine.  But I'd hate to write any code that depended on that.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript objects properties historically do not have a defined order. While property order has been defined in more recent versions of the ECMAScript specification, the logic is complex and contains a number of edge cases. It is therefore best not to rely on the order of object properties.

However, since you're facing restrictions imposed by a badly designed endpoint, what you could do is create a mapping to define the old/new property names, and then use [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) and [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to recreate the object with the properties in the same order:

```
const result = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(data).map(([k, v]) => [k in mapping ? mapping[k] : k, v])
);
```

---

**Complete snippet:**

```js
const data = {
  ilbquc: '',
  ilsttci: '',
  isttcp: '',
  InvoiceTaxTotal: '',
  it: '',
  InvoiceLineID: '',
  WST: '',
  VERFAHREN: '',
  BxLxH: '',
  GEW: '',
  HINWEISE: '',
  ilbquc: '',
  ilsttci: '',
  isttcp: '',
  it: ''
};

const mapping = {
  'ilbquc': 'InvoiceLineBaseQuantityUnitCode',
  'ilsttci': 'InvoiceLineSubTotalTaxCategoryID',
  'isttcp': 'InvoiceSubTotalTaxCategoryPercent',
  'it': 'InvoiceTotal/InvoicePayableAmount'
};

const result = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(data).map(([k, v]) => [k in mapping ? mapping[k] : k, v])
);

console.log(result);
```